# Adding a link help - adds the address of current page to start of each link I make?

Tags: html, css, web

This is easier to explain by writing what happens.

If my web page is www.anything.com and I want to add a link to Google, I would do this:

```
<a href="www.google.com;">hello</a>
```

But, I always get the name of the page added to the beginning of the link. So if someone clicked hello, they'd go to www.anything.com/www.google.com

I don't have much programming experience, so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

You should add the full (absolute) path of the webaddress: `http://www.google.com`.

Everything which doesn't start with `http://` (or another protocol), `mailto:` or will just be used. Everything else will be relative.

Same goes for local links (which always should be relative):

```
<a href="/file.html">Test</a>
```

This will be relative to the document root.

```
<a href="file.html">Test</a>
```

This will be relative to the current path.

Answer (score 0):

Use `http://www.google.com/` instead of `www.google.com` (absolute path instead of relative)